# How can i get via JS the height of a div and assign that height to another div?

Tags: javascript, html, height

Pretty much title. I have tried everything on stackoverflow without any results

I am sorry,i am still new to stackoverflow and have no idea how to ask properly a question and format it right.Here is the code that i tried

`var firstDivHeight= document.getElementById('#div1').clientHeight;
document.getElementById("#div2").style.height = firstDivHeight;`

Comment: could you show, what you've tried ?

Comment: [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Showing some of the HTML, JS and CSS you're using would be helpful too

Comment: Please be more clear on what you are asking, add code you have tried.

Comment: *"I have tried everything on stackoverflow without any results"* - I **highly** doubt that. This isn't a new question, please show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate first div height and then assign to the second div

```
var firstDivHeight= document.getElementById('first_div_id').clientHeight;
document.getElementById("second_div_id").style.height = firstDivHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use jQuery but in Javascript should be like this

```js
var Height = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
var Width = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetWidth;
var otherdiv=document.getElementById('otherDiv');
otherdiv.style.height=Height+'px';
otherdiv.style.width=Width+'px';
document.write('Height:'+Height+'px');
document.write('Width:'+Width+'px');
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="width:80%;height:70px; background:green">Bla</div>
<div id="otherDiv" style="background:red">ble</div>
```

document